# Slow Pi (running pihole) due to large MicroSD with only one partition?

Tags: sd-card, performance

My piholePi seems somewhat slow.

- It is a *Raspberry Pi 2 Model B Rev 1.1*, so 4 cores @ 900 mhz.
- Runs Pi OS Buster
- Running the Pi OS Lite version

Here is the general load, of `top -d 10`

[image]

Sometimes, even opening a flat-file with `vi (vim)` takes 3 seconds or more!

I have a MicroSD from 128 GB in it, only one partition.

Would it help if I created 1 partition for the OS, let's say 15 GB, and the rest for data, and mount it under /data or so?

Do you know any benchmark-scripts anyway that I could run for analysis?

Thanks all!

A

added:

`top -d 10` output of 2 *older and much slower* Raspberry Pi **"1"** Model B Rev 2:

[image]

And the other one:

[image]

Comment: You could just check `top` to see which processes are currently using most ressources. Anything that pops into your eyes there?

Comment: Done this, and it does not show anything I recognize as strange. I have updated my initial post.

Comment: SYSTEM CRASH: I ran rpi-benchmark on 3 pi's, 2 x model "1" and 1 model "2"

On the model 1 it ran OK.

On the model 2, it crashed my system. It ran OK, but immediately after that I got segfaults, and after reboot I get SMP errors: SMP : failed to stop secondary CPUs after running rpi-benchmark

Anyone familiar with this???

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 23 Dec 2020: resizing the rootfs to 20 GB speeds up the Pi a lot, yet mounting the other 100 GB under /data slows down the system dramatically.

See also this post:
[Mounting partition in fstab slows Pi dramatically](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/119499/mounting-partition-in-fstab-slows-pi-dramatically)

UPDATE May 2021: I forgot to update this topic, but I ended up investing € 8 or so in 2 new fast MicroSD cards of 16 & 32 GB. All works stable and fast now.